# Change icon in validationsummary in silverlight

Tags: .net, xaml, silverlight, validationsummary

I want to change the icon at the top left corner in the validation summary because it's not company compliant.

[image: validation summary icon]

Is this possible? I found nothing on google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon is encoded in the ValidationSummary's HeaderTemplate. The original template is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894489%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (Search for `<Path Fill="#DDD43940" Data="M5.5,2.5 L7.5,2.5 L7.5,8 L5.5,8 M5.5,9.5 L7.5,9.5 L7.5,10.5 L5.5,10.5"/>` - this is the exclamation mark).

Here's an example of how to customize the header:

```
<ctl:ValidationSummary>
  <ctl.ValidationSummary.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Border Background="#FFDC020D">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Image Source="/MyCustomImage.png" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ctl.ValidationSummary.HeaderTemplate>
</ctl:ValidationSummary>
```